# How to save tensorflow dataset as TFRecord file?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, tf.keras, tfrecord

How to save or convert tensorflow dataset as TFRecord file?
I would like to convert my data from csv file to TFRecord  to speed up training.

```
titanic = pd.read_csv("https://storage.googleapis.com/tf-datasets/titanic/train.csv")
titanic.head()
```

Comment: Can the contents of your CSV fit into memory? If so, TFRecord is not going to speed up training.

Comment: @geometrikal, csv content is bigger than memory size.  Good point, of course TFRecord speed up time of readinig data not time of trainig model

Comment: Actually if CSV is bigger than memory, a TFrecord will be faster for training as it is a flat file already in binary format and thus reading each batch will be fast

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of creating TFRecords for object detection:

https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/using_your_own_dataset.md

Modify to suit your own data format